# Does the Golden Monkey change ALL cards put into your deck?

Tags: hearthstone

The golden monkey is a card that changes all the cards in your deck and your hand into random legendary cards.

I've noticed that it does not change a Burrowing Mine into a legendary. Does it also not change Ambush cards that are in my deck if a Rogue plays Beneath The Grounds, etc...

[image] [image]

Comment: What is the actual question?  You ask "Does it change all cards", but proceed to answer it yourself by pointing out two that do not get changed.

Comment: on an unrelated sidenote if you put cards in your deck using gang up even after a mistcaller has been plays the cards put in still get the buff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like The Golden Monkey is bugged.
Some people have reported that it will not change all the cards put into your deck, others have claim that it will.

## Sources for "Does not change added cards":

- Your own experience, with the [Burrowing Mine](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/hearthstone.gamepedia.com/thumb/1/12/Burrowing_Mine%2812345%29.png/200px-Burrowing_Mine%2812345%29.png?version=a1b12d73a14a9f1df723400f79b8a896) (created by [Iron Juggernaut](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/hearthstone.gamepedia.com/thumb/b/b0/Iron_Juggernaut%2812295%29.png/184px-Iron_Juggernaut%2812295%29.png?version=d13d9c3ce00a5cbaba1d38295645b514)),
- And by people on [the Hearthstone Fourms](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/20200509948) with [Beneath the Grounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Efa.png)

## Sources for "Changes added cards":

- [This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWZxEK9QOug&feature=youtu.be) showing a custom match between two friends, the warrior uses the Juggernaut but the priest decks out and never draws a mine.
- A [collection of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf3V5.jpg) showing a match against [Archaedas](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Archaedas), in which the AI uses the golden monkey, but never takes 10 damage after, thus he had never drawn the [Burrowing Mine](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/hearthstone.gamepedia.com/thumb/1/12/Burrowing_Mine%2812345%29.png/200px-Burrowing_Mine%2812345%29.png?version=a1b12d73a14a9f1df723400f79b8a896)

From the people that have said it does not change, I have not seen actual visual proof,
but there is visible proof of people showing it does change added cards.
This leads me to believe that the answer to your question "Does the Golden Monkey change ALL cards put into your deck?" is

**Yes, the Golden Monkey changes ALL cards in your deck, including cards placed there due to an effect. However there also seems to currently be a bug where it may exclude cards added by an effect.**

Answer (score 3):

Was burrowing mine played after you played the Golden Monkey?

If so, that's the reason, it only changes all the cards currently in your deck. Any cards added after the battlecry effect triggers will not be changed.

Comment: on an unrelated sidenote if you put cards in your deck using gang up even after a mistcaller has been plays the cards put in still get the buff

Comment: Why should it be possible to play Burrowing Mine or any non legendary card after the Golden Monkey? Golden Monkey should replace all cards in the deck and hand with legendary minions as the card text says, so that no non legendary should be left. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @hoodlamic1 The mistcaller effect is due to a different mechanic: https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/3zq8sg/til_mistcaller_effect_survives_the_golden_monkey/

Comment: @Rob Burrowing mine is played by the **opponent** and they are putting cards into your deck. If they add the cards **after** you've played Golden Monkey the cards won't be changed. If they played the card **before** you played Golden Monkey then the card will be changed as well. It's no different than any other battle cry effect in the game.

Comment: @Sorean Oops, I should have looked up Burrowing Mine before... Sorry!